# Facebook login through android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a facebook app for android with the following functions:Login to facebook and Post to wall 
help me!
I have to check if official facebook app is installed in user's device. If yes then it will login from that app only otherwise it will open fb browser. I checked that thing but problem is that after logging through fb app it doesnot come to its own app. It continue to stay on facebook app. How to return to my own app after login to fb

Answer (score 0):

You need a Session.StatusCallback listener. Click the "Step 2: Set up authentication change triggers" hyperlink on this page for details:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/

Answer (score 0):

This is very common question in android application. if you want to know steps to integrate facebook then please refer below link carefully and do not miss any step.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

After refer this you will able to work with api of facebook.If you have any query then please ask me.

Best of luck. Enjoying ANDROID :)